# What would the java code be for sorting the characters in each word of a string?

Tags: java, string, sorting

I don't want a string with the words sorted alphabetically. I need the letters of each word arranged alphabetically, but the order of words to remain the same. 
Eg: Input string: welcome to java, Output string: ceelmow ot aajv

Comment: This is not "rent a coder" website

Comment: Let me give you some hints: comparable, comparator, split. Now you join the dots.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  String str = "welcome to java";
  String strs[] = str.split(" ");
  char[] ch;
  StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(str.length());
  for (int i=0; i<strs.length; i++) {
    ch = strs[i].toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(ch);
    strBuilder.append(ch);
    if (i != strs.length - 1) {
        strBuilder.append(" ");
    }
  }
  System.out.println(strBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: Trailing white-space :P

Comment: updated just now although not a biggie ;)

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved using 5 steps

1) Split the String to words using `foo.split(" ")`
2) Get all the characters in the String using `char[] bar=foo.toCharArray()`
3) Sort the array using `Arrays.sort(bar)`
4) Turn the characters in a String using `new String(bar)`
5) Put all the characters back to a sentence

Don't forget to mind that capitals will come *before* not-capitals

Let me know if it works (or not)
Happy coding :) -Charlie

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StackOverflowExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "welcome to java";
        String[] words = s.split(" ");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                sb.append(" ");
            }
            char[] wordCharArray = words[i].toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(wordCharArray);
            sb.append(wordCharArray);
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```